# Remove saved double quotes in string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

For some unknown reason, some of my saved strings (in db) have a leading and trailing `\"`.

How do I detect and remove these?

`my_object.a_string_type_attribute.gsub(/\s|"|'/, '')` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Show your console output. Maybe it's just escape character for `"`.

Comment: Yes it is an escape character for `"`.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: This is how my string looks like `"\"a_word\""`. I don't want the inner quotes. The regex provided in the question doesn't catch the double quotes :(

Comment: It looks like this because Ruby escapes `"` automatically when outputting your string to console. If you type `puts "\"a_word\""`, you'll see the string is correct.

Comment: But I don't want the inner qoutes? There has to be a way to remove them.

Comment: You can try like this this for e.g. 

`input = "\/\\dfsdfsdgdfg!@#$$",
input = input.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do sth in lines:

```
YourModel.where('column_name LIKE \'"%"\'').each do |model|
  model.column_name = model.column_name[1..-2]
  model.save
end
```

It might take a while if you have large database. Make sure to create a backup if you want to run it against your live database.

Answer (score 0):

```
string.strip('"')
```

should work.